# Submodule of a noetherian module is noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, module-isomorphism

> Assume $R$ is a ring, $\psi:M\rightarrow N$ a surjective $R$-modules homomorphism. Then, $M$ is noetherian $\iff$ $N$ and $K=\operatorname{Ker}(\psi)$ are noetherian.

So I proved $\leftarrow$. Now I assume $M$ is noetherian. It's not hard to show $N$ is noetherian since $\psi$ is surjective. Now I tried to prove that $K$ is noetherian - I took $K'\subseteq K$ a submodule of $K$. So, $K'\subseteq M$ and therefore it's a submodule in $M$ and so if finitely generated. Is my reasoning correct or am I missing something (maybe the fact that it's finitely generated in $M$ doesn't mean its finitely generated in $K$?).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm not yet familiar with exact sequences

Comment: No problem, the short exact sequence $0\rightarrow K \rightarrow M \xrightarrow{\psi} N\rightarrow 0$ is just summarizing what you have. The second map is injective, $\psi$ is surjective and $M/K\cong N$. The proof in the duplicate is not using exact sequences, just module homomorphisms. So $M$ is Noetherian iff $N$ and $K$ are Noetherian. Just follow the proof.